# React CRUD app :How to get Submit Button working

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, crud

Trying to make a React CRUD App (ASP.Net Core).
The Submit button is not working.
my code is as follows.
Can someone please point out what I could be doing wrong? Many Thanks.

```
<Fragment>
                <div className="Menubar" style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
                <Button
                    onClick={() => this.setState({ newSaleModal: true })}
                    color="green">New Sale</Button>
                <Modal
                    id="modal"
                    open={this.state.newSaleModal}
                    onOpen={() => this.setState({ newSaleModal: true })}

                >
                    <Modal.Header >Add a new sale</Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Content>
                        <Form onSubmit={this.addSale}>
                            <Form.Field>
                                <Label>Date sold</Label><br />
                                <input type="date" onChange={this.handleDateChange} value={this.state.date} placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
                                    defaultValue={this.state.saleList.date} required /> <br />
                            </Form.Field>
                            <Form.Field>
                                <Label>Customer</Label><br />
                                <Dropdown

                                    options={customerListData.map(customer => {
                                        return {
                                            key: customer.id,
                                            text: customer.name,
                                            value: customer.id
                                        }
                                    })}
                                    placeholder='Customer Name'
                                    onChange={this.handleCustomerDataChange}
                                    value={this.state.selectedCustomer}
                                    selection /> <br />
                            </Form.Field>
```

Rest of the New sale form code
<Form.Field>
Product
<Dropdown
clearable
options={productListData.map(product => {
return {
key: product.id,
text: product.name,
value: product.id
}
})}
placeholder='Product Name'
onChange={this.handleProductDataChange}
value={this.state.selectedProduct}
selection /> 
</Form.Field>
<Form.Field>
Store
<Dropdown
clearable
options={storeListData.map(store => {
return {
key: store.id,
text: store.name,
value: store.id
}
})}
placeholder='Store Name'
onChange={this.handleStoreDataChange}
value={this.state.selectedStore}
selection /> 
</Form.Field>
<Button onClick={() => this.setState({ newCustomerModal: false })}>Cancel
Save

</Modal.Content>

Comment: Where is the submit button?

Comment: Where `addSale`?

Comment: Can you expand on your comment "The Submit button is not working".  What is happening when you click the button? Does the button appear, or just not navigating when clicked?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.